# Firefox print to pdf not applying @media print rules in landscape mode

Tags: html, css

I wrote some simple CSS rules to prevent some parts of a page from printing.
My `div id="ad-pages-right-sidebar"` has the following CSS attached to it:

```
@media print
{
    #ad-pages-right-sidebar
    {
        display:none;
    }

}
```

The problem is, while using the Print to PDF feature in Firefox, the `div` is still visible on the printed page, but only when I set up the page to be printed in landscape mode.

This only happens in Firefox and only in landscape mode.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please post for others.

Comment: I didn't find a good solution to fix the problem, I had to rewrite the entire markup and CSS. So, no solutions from me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect the element in landscape mode to see if any css is overridden?

Also,
Insert a stylesheet just for print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/print.css" media="print" />
```

Then put CSS to hide the div in that stylesheet and see if that works.

```
#ad-pages-right-sidebar
{
    display:none;
}
```

Having a separate stylesheet or inline code for handling print (in the right order) prevents a lot of override errors.

Bit more info on Print Style Sheets:
http://www.webcredible.com/blog/print-stylesheet-definitive-guide/